# Group rows count besides latest record

Tags: mysql

I can have a `group by` clause which returns latest record of each group in the way this query is running:

```
select `id`, `user_id`, `type`, `product_id`
    from `table` where `id` in 
        (select max(`id`) from `table` where `product_id`=1 group by `type`)
order by `id` group by `type`
```

But also I want to have number of rows within each group that is counted in a normal `group by` query.

```
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|   type   | select count(1) where type=:type group by type; |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|   one    |                        5                        |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|   two    |                        1                        |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|   three  |                        109                      |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to have these numbers as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a `JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.id,t.user_id,t.type,t.product_id,s.cnt
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT p.type,max(p.id) as max_id,count(*) as cnt
            FROM YourTable p
            WHERE p.product_id = 1
            GROUP BY p.type) s
 ON(t.id = s.max_id)
WHERE t.product_id = 1
```

Now the derived table `s` will contain for each `type` the `max(id)` and the `count` , and by joining to it , it will filter all the other records.

Comment: Thank you but doesn't it seem costly as we have to join two tables for having that numbers?

Comment: @revo Using `JOIN` , and using a subquery `where ID in(...)` will probably cost the same, and most likely the `JOIN` will perform better.

Comment: I then probably should dive into SQL a lot. Accepted!